# Can't resolve 'child_process' in '...\node_modules\open\lib'

Tags: reactjs, npm, embedded-browser

I have my React project, and I'm trying to import and use 
[react-embedded-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-embedded-browser)

but I'm getting this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   'C:...\projectName\node_modules\open\lib'

Hints:

- I integrated this project with ExtReact, (but still the project works OK just until I *npm install react-embedded-browser*
- I see that this npm package was updated last time 3 years ago (so it might be deprecated)
- **what should I use to Embed Web Browser into my WebPage if not this package** (it can Not be a native)?

> ```
> import React, {Component} from 'react';
> import EmbeddedBrowser from 'react-embedded-browser';
>
> function show() {
>   let eb = document.querySelector('.embedded-browser');
>   eb.className = 'embedded-browser anime-slidein';
>   eb.open('https://google.com');
> }
>
> class EmbeddedBrowserComponent extends Component{
>   render(){
>       return (
>           <div>
>               <button type="button" onClick={show}>push me</button>
>               <EmbeddedBrowser id="scaffolded-browser" />
>       </div>
>       )
>   }
> }
>
> export default EmbeddedBrowserComponent;
> ```

Comment: Please provide some code where you are using embedded browser.

Answer (score 0):

just put in **package.json**

```
"browser":{
"child_process": false
}
```

or `{ fork: false }`

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thank you anyway for trying to help.

Comment: Have you imported react-embedded-browser in your component?

Comment: Yes, I did.
I was strictly following this example: 
https://github.com/rhysd/react-embedded-browser/tree/master/example

Comment: I have also the same problem, and this does not help. sorry.